# most amount of field of day django

Tags: python, django, list, django-models, django-views

I want to list the most amounts of field of a model for each day for example this be my model:

```
class Topic(Model.models): 
    title = models.Charfield(max_lenth=40)
    total_responses = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(add_now=True)
```

I have imported **Max** before in my *views.py* and this is my query set:

```
query = Topic.objects.values(
            'date','total_responses',
        ).order_by('-date').aggregate(Max('total_responses'))
```

I am sending this query to *template*  but it returns all models! but I just need the max amount of **each day** model

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the row which contains the max value of **total_responses** field for the current day, your query should be something like this:

```
from django.utils.timezone import datetime #important if using timezones
today = datetime.today()
query = Topic.objects.values(
            'date','total_responses',
        ).filter(
            date__year=today.year, 
            date__month=today.month, 
            date__day=today.day,
        ).order_by('-total_responses').first()
```

This will give you only 1 row for each day with max **total_responses**